# Setting Current User Location for locationpicker.jquery.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, web-applications, geolocation

I am using [locationpicker.jquery.js](http://logicify.github.io/jquery-locationpicker-plugin/) and im trying to supply the variables for longitude and latitude before it loads so that the user can load from his or her specific location.

```
  $('.map').locationpicker({
      location: {
          latitude: 10.621760,
          longitude: 121.107015
      },
      radius: 10,
      inputBinding: {
          latitudeInput: $('.map-lat'),
          longitudeInput: $('.map-lon'),
          radiusInput: $('.map-radius'),
          locationNameInput: $('.map-address'),
          scrollwheel: true
      },
      enableReverseGeocode: true
  });

  $( document ).ready(function() {
      navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
      function showPosition(position) {
          $('.map-lat').val(position.coords.latitude);
          $('.map-lon').val(position.coords.longitude);
      }
  });
```

I have tried putting jquery selectors and putting them into the variables for latitude and longitude. I have tried setting a hidden input field and passing these to latitude and longitude; but they just fail. Is there something I can do to make locationpicker load at the user's location? latitude and longitude does not seem to accept any other types of variables other than numbers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the issue you're having is that `getCurrentLocation` is an asynchronous process. This means that you need to load the map after that process has completed.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
  function showPosition(position) {
      var lat = position.coords.latitude;
      var lng = position.coords.longitude;
      $('.map-lat').val(lat);
      $('.map-lon').val(lng);
      buildMap(lat, lng);
  }
});
```

Pass in the `lat` and `lng` arguments and convert them to a floating-point number (`+lat`...), otherwise use the defaults.

```
function buildMap(lat, lng) {
  $('.map').locationpicker({
    location: {
      latitude: +lat || 10.621760,
      longitude: +lng || 121.107015
    },
    radius: 10,
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now, `getCurrentPosition()` and `watchPosition()` no longer work on insecure origins. To use this feature, you should consider switching your application to a secure origin, such as **HTTPS**.